# Can SPI slave work with wrong clockphase setting?

Tags: adc, spi, clock

In our prototype board, we have one 16-bit SPI based ADC [ad 7798] and an SPI based switch [adg1414].

Though some other guy has written the driver for it, and its also working. However when I analysed, I think the Clock and Phase settings are wrong.

I am attaching the timing diagrams for both slaves.
Please can anyone tell me, if the settings that I am assuming is right?

[image: AD7798]

ckpl = HIGH

ckph = High

But In our driver code its written as

ckpl = HIGH

CKPH = LOW

Still it works.. Does any one have idea, how it's working?

Answer (score 1):

By Motorola SPI timing diagram, your ADC's configuration should be

CPOL = 1, (SCK Normal High)

CPHA = 1, (The data is effective the the second edge, at your case, it's a rising edge)

There also has a TI version SPI:

> Some products use different naming conventions. For example, the TI
>   MSP430 uses the name UCCKPL instead of CPOL, **and its UCCKPH is the
>   inverse of CPHA.** When connecting two chips together, the clock phase
>   initialization values must be examined to be sure of using the right
>   settings.

So, for TI version, it should be

CKPL = 1,

CKPH = 0.

By the naming method in your code, it seems the code use TI mode, and are you using a TI MCU? If it is, then CKPH should be 0.

So, read the code carefully, not just the comment, make sure you understand the code completely.

---

**Update:**

Actually, most ADI's SPI based ADC, has a standard write timing, bus use a **modified** SPI read timing diagram.

From the write timing you should make the data effective at the second CLK edge. So, for Motorola version: CPHA = 1, for TI version: CKPH = 0.

For the read timing: When the ADC complete the conversion. It first output a "low" level at the DOUT line, to indicate the user, the data is ready. And you send the clock and clock out the remaining data. The remaining data will be clocked out after t2 from your first edge. So, you must avoid the extra low bit, and use CKPH = 0.

Whichever settings you use, given your finally timing (considering the various parasitic factor) don't violate the timing diagram, it will work.

Comment: ya I have read the code carefully,the controller is MSP430F6438. Thats why I am confused, even i thought the setting the same that u said, but it working with opposite phase

Comment: If you reverse the phase and it works too. Then i think you may using a fast SPI clock, and your 1/(4f) is shorter than \$t_{9}\$. You can try use low SPI speed and look if it still works.

Comment: No, If i reverse the phase then ,it gives some values that are wrong, I am using 4Mhz clock speed. The slave is allowed to work much beyond this speed as per datasheet.      Could it be the track parasitic capitance that is changing the phase of the cock, which make the slave to work with wrong phase settings. However the track length is about 3 cm.  I will check the signal waveform on Scope and post it here. May be that will help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: "If you reverse the phase and it works too.", i mean your post said, if you reverse the phase and it **work**. That is, no matter CKPH = 0 or 1, all work, right? **work** means no wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

When used in normal fashion, an SPI port will be configured so as to yield a timing margin of +/- 1/2 bit time between the clock and data wires.  Inverting the phase of the clock will increase the timing margin to a full bit time on one side but decrease it to zero on the other.  Depending upon what one knows about the relative propagation delays of the clock and data wires, that may or may not be a good thing.

There are many situations where such a skewed tolerance would be a bad thing; in cases where propagation times for clock and data are small, but one has no particular reason to believe one is larger than the other, having such skewed tolerance would make things unworkable.  In many other situations, however, where it is known that the data at a certain point will be significantly delayed relative to the clock (including the very common situation of a slave feeding data to the master), such skew may actually be advantageous.

If the slave is feeding data to the master, the master can be guaranteed to have see each clock edge before the slave can possibly see it and return data.  Thus, it is generally safe to have the slave send outgoing data on the same clock edge as the master will have used to sample the previous bit.  Indeed, using such an approach may increase the speed at which data may be transmitted reliably (with normal SPI, round-trip time from master to slave must be under half a bit time; inverting the clock will extend that to almost a full bit time).